# List view activity showing objects only the first time it is opened

Tags: android, json

In my Android app I have a list view activity showing MySQL objects downloaded from a web server via JSON.

I have detected following issue: the first time the activity is shown, the JSON objects are shown fine, but if the user goes back to the previous activity and then opens the list view activity again, any object is shown on the list and no error is thrown.

I need your help to solve this issue. Here is the activity code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ofertas_list extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombreCategoria";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "idCategoria";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORIAS = "Categorias";

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://xxxxxxxx/android_ofertaslist.php?id=";





    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA = "nombreEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_IDEMPRESA = "idEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA = "descripcionEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_STRIMAGEN = "strImagen";
    private static final String TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA = "direccionEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA = "telefonoEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA = "facebookEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_EMAILEMPRESA = "emailEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_TEXTOOFERTA = "textoOferta";
    private static final String TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA = "horarioEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA = "categoriaEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA = "latitudEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA = "longitudEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA = "valoracionEmpresa";



    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias);


     // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
     // JSON node keys

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        this.url = url+email;
        this.setTitle(name);
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                //cambiar por los nuevos campos
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();


                //Starting single contact activity
                //cambiar por los nuevos campos
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, cost);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ofertas_list.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Cargando datos...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIAS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                        String nombreEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA);
                        String descripcionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA);
                        String strImagen = c.getString(TAG_STRIMAGEN);
                        String direccionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA);
                        String telefonoEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA);
                        String facebookEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA);
                        String emailEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_EMAILEMPRESA);
                        String textoOferta = c.getString(TAG_TEXTOOFERTA);
                        String horarioEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA);
                        String categoriaEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA);
                        String valoracionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA);
                        String latitudEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA);
                        String longitudEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA);
                        String idEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_IDEMPRESA);




                        // Phone node is JSON Object

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_IDEMPRESA, idEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA, nombreEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA,descripcionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_STRIMAGEN,strImagen);
                        contact.put(TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA,direccionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA,telefonoEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA,facebookEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAILEMPRESA,emailEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_TEXTOOFERTA,textoOferta);
                        contact.put(TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA,horarioEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA,categoriaEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA,valoracionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA,latitudEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA,longitudEmpresa);






                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ofertas_list.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item_ofertas, new String[] { TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA, TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA}, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ofertas_list extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombreCategoria";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "idCategoria";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORIAS = "Categorias";

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://xxxxxxx/android_ofertaslist.php?id=";



    // URL to get contacts JSON
   // private static String url = "http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/android_ofertaslist.php";

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA = "nombreEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_IDEMPRESA = "idEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA = "descripcionEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_STRIMAGEN = "strImagen";
    private static final String TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA = "direccionEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA = "telefonoEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA = "facebookEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_EMAILEMPRESA = "emailEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_TEXTOOFERTA = "textoOferta";
    private static final String TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA = "horarioEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA = "categoriaEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA = "latitudEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA = "longitudEmpresa";
    private static final String TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA = "valoracionEmpresa";

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias);


     // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
     // JSON node keys

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        this.url = url+email;
        this.setTitle(name);
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                //cambiar por los nuevos campos
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();


                //Starting single contact activity
                //cambiar por los nuevos campos
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, cost);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ofertas_list.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Cargando datos...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIAS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                        String nombreEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA);
                        String descripcionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA);
                        String strImagen = c.getString(TAG_STRIMAGEN);
                        String direccionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA);
                        String telefonoEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA);
                        String facebookEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA);
                        String emailEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_EMAILEMPRESA);
                        String textoOferta = c.getString(TAG_TEXTOOFERTA);
                        String horarioEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA);
                        String categoriaEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA);
                        String valoracionEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA);
                        String latitudEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA);
                        String longitudEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA);
                        String idEmpresa = c.getString(TAG_IDEMPRESA);




                        // Phone node is JSON Object

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_IDEMPRESA, idEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA, nombreEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA,descripcionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_STRIMAGEN,strImagen);
                        contact.put(TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA,direccionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_TELEFONOEMPRESA,telefonoEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_FACEBOOKEMPRESA,facebookEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAILEMPRESA,emailEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_TEXTOOFERTA,textoOferta);
                        contact.put(TAG_HORARIOEMPRESA,horarioEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_CATEGORIAEMPRESA,categoriaEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_VALORACIONEMPRESA,valoracionEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA,latitudEmpresa);
                        contact.put(TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA,longitudEmpresa);






                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ofertas_list.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item_ofertas, new String[] { TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA, TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA}, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `new GetContacts().execute()` in `onResume()` method.

`onCreate()` is called when you start Activity for the first time. If you leave activity, without killing it, and come back, your app goes thru `onStart() ->`onResume()`

Put `onResume` right before `onCreate` and remove `new GetContacts().execute();` from `onCreate()`.

```
...
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias);
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I have included the following in my activity:    protected void onResume()
        {
         new GetContacts().execute();

       } but the issue is not solved.

Comment: You can't make it protected, you will Override an existing method. I will update my answer

Comment: It seems like you added it in AsynTask. Can you update your code where did you add it?

Comment: I have added your proposed code in my activity and exactly where you said, but now an error is thrown when trying to open the activity.

Comment: plus update your code so i can see if u have made mistake somewhere

Comment: The error says ... Unable to resume activity...Activity did not call through to super.onResume()...

Comment: My bad. Forgot to call super.onResume(). Check my code above again.

Comment: now the app behaviour is different. The first time the activity is shown, the progressDialog doesn't disappear after all objects have been downloaded, the objects are shown on the background but the progressDialog doesn't stop working.. I have updated my question to show the current code. Thank you again for your time and patience.

Comment: and I have detected that the objects are downloaded twice, it seems that the GetContacts().execute() is executed at least two times or in a loop...

Comment: I have told you to delete this from onCreate() : `new GetContacts().execute();` Read about Activity lifecycle.

Comment: you are right, sorry for that. But the first issue is not solved. The first time the activity is shown, the objects are populating the list view, but going back to the previous activity and opening again the activity, the objects are not shown.

Comment: arik.gokhan@yahoo.com.tr

Answer (score 2):

You should probably perform the "`new GetContacts().execute();`" call in `onResume()`. See the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) to get more familiar with the Android Activity lifecyle.

`onCreate()` is only called when the Activity is created. In your testing, the Activity is probably usually still alive, so onCreate() will not always be called when re-entering the Activity.

Comment: Thank you, I have included the following in my activity:    protected void onResume()
        {
         new GetContacts().execute();

       } but the issue is not solved.